# How to control which edges are selected after beveling operation is complete?

Tags: modeling

In 02:05 of this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GU6fYiujrlI&t=2m05s

some edges are beveled multiple times. However, when I try to do the same in Blender, after finishing my fist bevel, the selected edges include short in-between edges, and not only the edges parallel to the bevel.

What I'm getting:

[image: unexpected after-bevel selection]

What should the after-bevel selection look like according to the video:

[image: expected behaviour]

I have to manually de-seclect everything and re-select only the edges I want to bevel again, while in the beforementioned video that is not the case. How do I achieve the same behaviour of the bevel tool like in the video?

Comment: Holding down Alt and clicking one of the long edges to select will select the entire loop.  Then holding shift+Alt+click on each additional edge will select everything there.  This would only 4 mouse clicks.

Comment: @MarcClintDion However in the video there are substantially more edges.

Answer (score 4):

That video was made with an older version of blender (2.64). You can now do pretty much the same thing faster by beveling (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) and then using the scroll wheel or the numbers on the keyboard to set the number of cuts:

[image]

---

Or you could deselect the edge rings with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>:

[image]

*Not exactly an optimal solution, but I don't think this is possible without using an older version of blender..*

Comment: While your solution is a good idea, the former, manual multiple beveling method allows a greater degree of control. In some situations even spacing of beveled edges is not desired.